# Функция подсчёта повторяющихся элементов в итерируемом объекте

Tags: python

Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает итерируемый объект и возвращает количество объектов, которые в этом итерируемом объекте встречаются больше одного раза:

```
def elements_count(iterable_object):
    summ = 0
    for i in iterable_object:
        if iterable_object.count(i)>1:
            summ += 1
    return (summ)
sequence = input().split(',')
print(elements_count(sequence))
```

Вот код функции, но она выводит не количество повторяющихся элементов, а количество повторов элементов. Например, если мы вводим [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5], то код выводит 6, а нужно 2. В чем ошибка?

Comment: вы 3 раза спрашиваете count(1) и 3 раза увеличиваете счетчик

Comment: Ну вы же к результату прибавляете единицу за каждый элемент, который имеет повторения. Именно это вы и получаете. Плюс, ваш код будет работать не с любыми итерируемыми объектами, а только с контейнерами. С генераторами, например, он работать не будет, т.к. у генераторов нет метода .count. Ну и ещё ваш код имеет квадратичную сложность, против линейно-логарифмической для оптимального алгоритма.

Comment: @splash58 как тогда задать i, что бы запрос был один для каждого элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def elements_count(iterable_object):
    x = {i for i in iterable_object if iterable_object.count(i) > 1}
    return len(x)


sequence = input('Input: ').split(',')
print(elements_count(sequence))
```

Можно использовать множество для элементов, удовлетворяющих условию и просто выводить его длину

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```
def elements_count(iterable_object):
    summ = 0
    for i in set(iterable_object):
        if iterable_object.count(i)>1:
            summ += 1
    return (summ)
sequence = input().split()
print(elements_count(sequence))
```